# Any editor that does autocompletion in Ubuntu?

Tags: gedit, vim, plugins, editor, auto-completion

Is there any editor/IDE(or a plugin for an existing editor like Vim or GEdit) that does auto-completion of many languages (not just C++)? Aptana does only HTML/CSS/JS and Code::Blocks does only C++ (I might be wrong on this one. If so, please correct me).

In Windows, Notepad++ does a pretty neat job.

Comment: I searched SO initially and found no good answers which are Ubuntu specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has a couple different forms of completion built-in for many programming languages.  Good places to start might be ":help 'complete'" and looking up [omni-completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Omni-completion along with [smart autocompletion using tabs](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_mapping_for_tab_completion) is a lifesaver!

Comment: If you're developing C, C++ or Python, [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is an amazing autocompleter for Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like **NetBeans**. It is multi-lingual, C++, Java, PHP to name a few, and what I like most about it, is that NetBeans unlike any other IDE **looks inside the header files you have included** and auto-completes not only the keywords and local variable names, but also more sophisticated names (for example, I use GTKmm library and NetBeans not only list me all possible completions, but also provides me with a documentation of any function I choose).

From my own research NetBeans is (unfortunately) the only IDE capable of that, so you may want to give it a try.

Comment: Netbeans is awesome and is the closest equivalent of Visual Studio in Linux. But it feels rather heavy.

Comment: It is, when you download it from the repo. Alternatively you can download the newer version from the website, where you can uncheck modules you don't need. For example, I chose ONLY C++, and is much lighter :)

Answer (score 1):

Editors in Unix can tend to set of language flame wars if one isn't careful. This is not my intention here at all. I started out using vim for code development and at some point shifted to emacs where I've stayed ever since, and that was over a decade ago. I have it configured to do autocompletion of all the languages I use (C/C++, Lisp, Python, Perl). But like any powerful editor it has a learning curve.

But vi/m is no different - I know hard core hackers who have it configured to do the same kinds of things I do. I think what it comes down to on some level is how you are wired - they're both extremely capable, very powerful code editors with more features than most people will ever be able to learn to use.

The problem I've noticed over the years with the IDE environments is that they may have a much shallower learning curve, but there's a reason for it. You have to gain elevation sometime if you want to get somewhere. A really good editor will force you to learn a lot of stuff early on and then get out of your way. The other ones don't force you to learn much (worth knowing) but are forever in your way after that.

Just my two cents.

jkcunningham

Answer (score 1):

Gedit provides a word completion plugin although I've not actually used it. Install gedit-plugins and you'll have it.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IDE is highly personal but do also have a look at [Geany](http://geany.org/). Do not let the rather basic website fool you: Geany supports a lot of [languages](http://www.geany.org/Main/AllFiletypes) out of the box and is very small (just 9Mb).

Answer (score 0):

**Komodo Edit** is a personal favourite and supports auto-completion, along with great other features ; look here for more details : http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for sublime_text http://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has autocompletion for most programming languages that it can handle. You may need to install the autocompletion package for your language of choice from Elpa, [Melpa](https://melpa.org/#/) or Marmalde.

Install emacs using:

```
Sudo apt install emacs
```